# Google Search Console "Fetch and Render" renders modal popups. What's the impact on SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, modal

Google's Search console allows you to "Fetch and Render" your web pages.

As you can see in the image below it's (unfortunately) clever enough to render the popup modal.

[image: Googlebot Render]

Is this likely to impact SEO negatively, since most of the viewport that Googlebot sees is blocked?

Should I add a check for the Bot's user agent to avoid showing the popup modal?

Comment: Can you change this so that the pop-up only comes up with an on-click event instead?? That my be the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this popup is supposed to let users who find their way directly from this page (via a search engine for example) that the product they are viewing is only being delivered via courier to certain postcodes, unlike a typical online store that delivers nationwide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will cause issues to your SEO as Googlebot is intelligent enough to identify content that has been greyed out by a modal such as this. If you are able to modify the site one option would be to do away with the modal and replace the quantity and order fields with the postcode selector, when they put in their postcode it will either show an error saying that they are outside the delivery area, or it will show the quantity field and order button, this way Googlebot will see the content it needs to see and index for your SEO and you can still ensure that you have the postcode verification you require prior to orders being placed.

Comment: Thanks, I've solved this solution by having the backend check if the request is being made by a crawler using the user agent. If it is a crawler, the Javascript code for showing the modal is not served to the client at all.