# SEO Ranking: Can we show pop ups after few seconds as google recommends not to show pop up that covers main content

Tags: seo, google-search-console, modal, pop-up

My question is related to this question:
[Google Search Console "Fetch and Render" renders modal popups. What's the impact on SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92247/google-search-console-fetch-and-render-renders-modal-popups-whats-the-impact)

I read that showing such pincode popup could penalize SEO ranking [here](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/08/helping-users-easily-access-content-on.html). How about a workaround that we show this after few seconds i.e. 1 or 2 seconds? Can google detect this and is it good thing to do from SEO perspective?

Comment: Using tricks to get around Google's detection will come back to bite you.

Comment: Not to mention annoying your users. Any site with a pop up and I leave. No exceptions. Google is exactly right about it being bad for user experience (UX). Take that as a hint!

Comment: When I visit a website and popups something... I know its a low quality site and leave.

Answer (score 1):

Bots of search engines are exploring the source code. We can say that bots look at your web pages as a web programmer - from the inside. Therefore, the answers to your questions:

> How about a workaround that we show this after few seconds i.e. 1 or 2 seconds?

This is manipulation to deceive Google and is associated with a violation of Google's recommendations. These actions have a high risk of sanctions from Google.

> Can google detect this...?

Of course, the Google bot can find this when examining the source code of your web pages.

> ...is it good thing to do from SEO perspective.?

Users want to get the information they need immediately, but not your information, which may be not related to their search. Users will see the deception of their expectations and walk away from your website as from a fraudulent. **SEO perspective**: Your website will lose users, and its rating will drop.